# Android: creating a transparent box with elements inside

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm currently working on an Android application and I'm at the point where I have to create a search engine. I created the basic outline but I just need to finish the design.

Here is what I have so far: current search engine
[image]

Here is the look I'm going for: look I'm going for
[image]

I already have a background photoshopped for this activity, and I'm basically trying to get what's in the first screenshot inside a box with a similar look to the second screenshot. I don't really know what to use to regroup my elements in. I was thinking of a drawable box maybe but I don't even know how to create that. I haven't found anyone trying to do this on StackOverflow and not much by googling how to achieve this look.

So do you have any suggestions to accomplish this look, maybe a library I'm not aware even exists? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one (linear or Relative)Layout not parent, put your code inside it and then give `android:background="#00ffffff"`

You can range it from 00 to FF (Hexa Decimal)

For maximum transparency => `#00555555` (Here 00 stands for the alpha)

For minimum or no transparency => `#FF555555` (Here FF stands for the alpha)

Comment: Problem is that I set my background ad a drawable with the background image, so I cannot apply transparency to that background using: android:background="#00ffffff"

Comment: Use FrameLayout ... upload your xml i will correct it.